# getting 400 Bad Request Error before calling controller method

Tags: spring-boot

I am not able to pass my request to controller layer I am getting `400 Bad Request` after passing through `OncePerRequestFilter`.

This happens only for POST Requests, its working fine for the `GET` Requests.

Below is my code in `Filter` class

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private UsersRestServices customUserDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        logger.info("token received---->" + requestTokenHeader);
        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
        // only the Token
        if (requestTokenHeader != null) {
            if (requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
                try {
                    logger.info("token for decoded--->" + jwtToken);
                    username = tokenProvider.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    httpServletResponse.sendError(403, "Illegal Argument Exception");
                } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                    logger.info("Token Expired");
                    httpServletResponse.sendError(403, "Token has Expired");
                }
            } else {
                logger.info("Token does not start with Bearer");
                httpServletResponse.sendError(403, "Token does not staet wity Bearer received:" + jwtToken);
            }
        }
        // Once we get the token validate it.
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
            // authentication
            if (tokenProvider.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                logger.info("sending token for validation----->");
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                logger.info("Authenticated the user successfully----->");
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));
                // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
                // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
                // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
                logger.info("setting Authentication in security context----->");
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                logger.info("Agter setting Authentication in security context----->");
            }
        }

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) httpServletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) httpServletResponse;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization,Content-Type,ClientName");

        // For HTTP OPTIONS verb/method reply with ACCEPTED status code -- per CORS handshake
        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
            return;
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

All the Above logs are getting printed in the console , Able to get data for GET Request, Problem is only for POST Requests

Below are the logs for the application

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)

2020-08-03 18:52:48.935  INFO 2021 --- [           main] com.qworks.claims.ClaimsApplication      : Starting ClaimsApplication on Naveens-MacBook-Air.local with PID 2021 (/Users/naveen/Documents/personal_dev/springboot/claims/target/classes started by naveen in /Users/naveen/Documents/personal_dev/springboot/claims)
2020-08-03 18:52:48.938  INFO 2021 --- [           main] com.qworks.claims.ClaimsApplication      : The following profiles are active: dev
2020-08-03 18:52:50.810  INFO 2021 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-08-03 18:52:50.962  INFO 2021 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 138ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-08-03 18:52:52.162  INFO 2021 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9090 (http)
2020-08-03 18:52:52.176  INFO 2021 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-08-03 18:52:52.176  INFO 2021 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2020-08-03 18:52:52.350  INFO 2021 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-08-03 18:52:52.350  INFO 2021 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3340 ms
2020-08-03 18:52:52.501  WARN 2021 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-08-03 18:52:52.784  INFO 2021 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-08-03 18:52:52.886  INFO 2021 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-08-03 18:52:53.037  INFO 2021 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2020-08-03 18:52:53.371  INFO 2021 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-08-03 18:52:53.662  INFO 2021 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-08-03 18:52:54.433  INFO 2021 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-08-03 18:52:54.489  INFO 2021 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-08-03 18:52:56.656  INFO 2021 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-08-03 18:52:56.671  INFO 2021 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-08-03 18:52:57.366  INFO 2021 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/v2/api-docs'], []
2020-08-03 18:52:57.366  INFO 2021 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/configuration/ui'], []
2020-08-03 18:52:57.366  INFO 2021 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/swagger-resources/**'], []
2020-08-03 18:52:57.367  INFO 2021 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/configuration/security'], []
2020-08-03 18:52:57.367  INFO 2021 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/swagger-ui.html'], []
2020-08-03 18:52:57.367  INFO 2021 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/webjars/**'], []
2020-08-03 18:52:57.432  INFO 2021 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@62108cd3, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7530090a, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@20820df0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5817f1ca, com.qworks.claims.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter@217235f5, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@55fb36de, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@320ff86f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7cd1ec54, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@38d525aa, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@42cc5460, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@fcd0e8d]
2020-08-03 18:52:57.474  INFO 2021 --- [           main] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]
2020-08-03 18:52:57.994  INFO 2021 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http) with context path ''
2020-08-03 18:52:57.996  INFO 2021 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2020-08-03 18:52:58.022  INFO 2021 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2020-08-03 18:52:58.066  INFO 2021 --- [           main] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
2020-08-03 18:52:58.305  INFO 2021 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-08-03 18:52:58.689  INFO 2021 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-08-03 18:52:58.706  INFO 2021 --- [           main] com.qworks.claims.ClaimsApplication      : Started ClaimsApplication in 10.476 seconds (JVM running for 11.105)
2020-08-03 18:53:04.137  INFO 2021 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-08-03 18:53:04.138  INFO 2021 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-08-03 18:53:04.156  INFO 2021 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 18 ms
2020-08-03 18:53:04.202  INFO 2021 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] c.q.c.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter   : token received---->Bearer ey<removed-for-stackoverflow>
2020-08-03 18:53:04.202  INFO 2021 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] c.q.c.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter   : token for decoded--->ey<removed-for-stackoverflow>
2020-08-03 18:53:04.866  INFO 2021 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] c.q.c.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter   : sending token for validation----->
2020-08-03 18:53:04.867  INFO 2021 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] c.q.c.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter   : Authenticated the user successfully----->
2020-08-03 18:53:04.868  INFO 2021 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] c.q.c.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter   : setting Authentication in security context----->
2020-08-03 18:53:04.869  INFO 2021 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] c.q.c.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter   : Agter setting Authentication in security context----->
```

Comment: What do you do in OncePerRequestFilter

Comment: @SimonMartinelli https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html

Comment: @Naveen Jagirdhar can you show us your logs? Also do you have `@RolesAllowed` annotations on your controller methods?

Comment: @Vusal i have updated the posts with logs, can you check , yes i have added these and verified by removing the annotations as well

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i am just validating the jwt tokens , i have updated Filter class